# Is there an app like ROM-control for non-AOKP roms?

Tags: applications, rom, aokp

I found ROM-control very useful in ICS. But it can only work on AOKP roms. So is there an app can do the same job on ROMs other than AOKP?

Comment: From searching it appears that this manages aspect of the user interface, is that correct?  If so then no, you can't do this on any arbitrary ROM because most ROMs don't have configurable settings for all those things.  You should look in Settings for what the ROM makes available.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, you cannot, because [ROM Control](https://github.com/AOKP/packages_apps_ROMControl) is an app that is geared and orientated towards Android 4 and in this instance AOKP, hence internal API's are different. Back porting it into a non-ICS/non-AOKP ROM may fail due to the dependencies on the aspect of AOKP, such as settings, and ICS internals are vastly different to non-ICS code.

If you are a programmer and like to torture yourself with the challenge of it, then maybe its possible to back-port certain aspects and build the ROM yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew is correct, these controls are specific to the ROM. Many [Cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/) ROMs offer settings like these, but there will be no way to access them without being built into the ROM you're using.

Answer (score -1):

not true. get xposed and there are a bunch of different tweak modules

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Could you elaborate on this? Where can we find this 'xposed' app?

Comment: And which are those "different tweak modules" solving the issue? Also, what is "not true"?

Comment: It's from the [XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1574401) and can "modify ROM". Quite useful and powerful.